# Specfiying that a parameter of an abstract method must be an enum

Tags: java, enums, abstract-class

I'm writing an abstract class in Java where I'd like a parameter of one of my abstract methods to be an enum, so I've got the following.  Note that only subclasses will know what possible states it can have. (Please excuse the contrived example)

```
public abstract class StateTracker {
    public abstract boolean isInState(???????? state);
}
```

What is ?????????  Therein lies the problem:

- Ideally it would be an abstract enum called StateEnum that has no instances, and the clients of StateTracker could make their own concrete StateEnums.  But we can't do anything like that in Java.
- I could make it an interface, but then I'd have no way of ensuring that the subclasses implement it as an enum, which is the goal.
- I could change it to **Enum < ? >**.  So I try that, and in my subclass I do something like this:

  ```
  public class MyStateTracker extends StateTracker {

      public enum MyState {
           BADSTATE_1, BADSTATE_2
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isInState(?!?!?!?! state) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
   }

  }
  ```

Now what is ?!?!?!?!  Here are the possibilities:

- MyState.  This doesn't compile since it doesn't think that I'm overriding the abstract method.
- Enum.  Same problem.

How can I ensure that concrete classes use an emum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to be able to ask a `StateTracker` whether it is in states declared by different `enum` types.

If you want to lock down the states so that a given state tracker can only be queried for one type of `enum`, create a generic type:

```
interface StateTracker<S extends Enum<S>> {
  boolean isInState(S state);
}

final class MyStateTracker implements StateTracker<MyStateTracker.MyState> {
  enum MyState { S1, S2 };
  private MyState state;
  ...
  @Override
  public boolean isInState(MyState state) {
    return state == this.state;
  }
}
```

If you have a couple of `enum` types defining states like this:

```
enum MyState { S1, S2 }
enum YourState { S1, S2 };
```

… and you want to be able to ask a `StateTracker` whether it is in any state (defined by any `enum`, really, unless you also declare a `State` marker interface for your `enum` to implement), then create a generic method:

```
interface StateTracker {
  <S extends Enum<S>> boolean isInState(S state);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class StateTracker<E extends Enum<E>> {
  public abstract boolean isInState(E state);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics to achieve this, Java's enums all extend implicitly [java.lang.Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html):

```
abstract class StateTracker<T extends Enum<?>> {
    public abstract boolean isInState(T state);
}

enum MyState {
    State_1, State_2
}

class State extends StateTracker<MyState>
{
    private MyState currentState = MyState.State_2;

    @Override
    public boolean isInState(MyState state)
    {
        return state.equals(currentState);
    }
}

public class TestEnum
{
    @Test
    public void testIsInState()
    {
        State state = new State();
        Assert.assertFalse(state.isInState(MyState.State_1));
        Assert.assertTrue(state.isInState(MyState.State_2));
    }
}

//This won't compile, so the generic-type must be an Enum
/*
class State2 extends StateTracker<String> //<-- Bound mismatch: The type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Enum<?>> of the type StateTracker<T>
{
    @Override
    public boolean isInState(String state)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }   
}
*/
```

Comment: You don't need to declare the `enum` externally.

Comment: D'oh! Of course I need to use the name of the class in front like in ericksons' answer. Live and learn... x)  I edited the wrong information from the answer.